# How to use a string as a selector in json data?

Tags: jquery, json

I want to use a String as a part of the addressing to json data using jQuery.

```
 var group = "AA";
 var products = {
        "AA": [
                   { "name": "1", "image": "/" },
                   { "name": "2", "image": "/" },
                   { "name": "3", "image": "/" }
        ]}
var name2 = products.parseSelector(group)[1].name;
```

The idea is to get **2** as result.
But it throws an Exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `parseSelector()`?  I've never seen that before.

Comment: `var name2 = products[group][1].name;`

Comment: PROTIP: When asking a question, *include* the text of the error/exception.  Don't just say "it throws an Exception".

Comment: P.S. This question has nothing to do with JSON.  JSON is a *string representation* of data that just so happens to *resemble* the code used to create a JavaScript object.  You have an object in JavaScript code, you do not have JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the object property.

```
var name2 = products[group][1].name;
```